# Upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04: No new release found

Tags: upgrade, 20.10, do-release-upgrade, 21.04

I would like to upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04. But do-release-upgrade returns "no new release found".

`/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`:

`Prompt=normal`

```
$cat /etc/lsb-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=groovy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.10"
```

I executed following steps:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt upgrade`
3. `sudo apt dist-upgrade`
4. `sudo apt autoremove`
5. `sudo do-release-upgrade`

but last steps returns "no new release found".

Do you have any hints what to check next?

Comment: The release of 21.04 specifically has been delayed because of a critical bug. See the mailing list post at https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-April/041448.html for information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly, Ubuntu version upgrades are not rolled out to everyone at once, and are done so steadily within about a week's time frame, to ensure that if some major breaking bug is discovered, Canonical can halt the upgrade until it is fixed, and not everyone becomes affected by said major breaking bug

Comment: It's not a specified time (about a week), yes there are weekly team meetings where it's commonly discussed (if not already out), but it's addressed more often than that

Comment: @guiverc I was talking about general time frame after a new version has been released, for users being able to upgrade to it (LTS to LTS aside)

Comment: Fair enough... but I do recall upgrades taking much longer than a week (even ignoring LTS releases) and not your "*within about a week's time frame*".  I would agree the *norm* is about a week though; or a few days over fitting your wording.. but I'd have preferred "usually" or more qualification (to allow for longer even if hopefully not anticipated).  Still a good answer and upvoted.